# Using st_read_db in R to read postGIS rasters

Tags: postgis, r, sql, sf

I use the st_read_db function in the sf package to read vector data from PostGIS into R. Can i use it to query rasters? ideally extract a raster value at a point:

```
require(sf)
# create connection to PostGIS
conn <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL",user="postgres",password="password",port=5432,dbname="postgis")

# example using query for polygons - fine
qry <- "SELECT * FROM polygontable WHERE arg1 = 10"
pols <- st_read_db(conn, query=qry, geom="geom")

# the following SQL works directly in PostGIS
qryras <- "SELECT rid, ST_Value(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y),27700))
FROM rastertable WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x,y),27700))"

# but does not work when passed to st_read_db
st_read_db(conn, query=qryras, geom="rast")

"Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, geom_column, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1"
```

With st_read_db being in the sf package, perhaps it only works for vector data?

*edit: this will work using dbGetQuery inside the RPostgreSQL package, but i specifically would like to know if sf will support what i want to do

Comment: What do you get back when you call it with dbGetQuery? And no, rasters are not supported `sf` objects, so if you are trying to get a PostGIS Raster back it will fail. Best you can do with `sf` is convert it to a set of gridded points with values. Rasters are best dealt with by the raster package.

Comment: dbGetQuery gives me the expected integer result. It's just a point extract on a raster stored in PostGIS. I want to interrogate a raster within PostGIS but to be honest dbGetQuery did the job.

Comment: These is no raster table in your query.

Comment: @Pierre, thanks i only just noticed i left the name as polygontable in my e.g. above, i have renamed it to rastertable (it was called something else in my PostGIS db anyway). Apologies. It works fine with; dbGetQuery(conn, qryras)